Working without setting memory limit in GKE Pods
We recently tried removing CPU and memory limit on pod and it gave better performance than with limit. The Pod is running java service with max heap set to 40G but non-heap use goes till 15 GB (memory mapped files) for specific large request.
Currently a node is configured to run max 10 such pods, and it works fanastically when combination of request is processed by 10 pods running on same node.
However scenario where all 10 pods running on same node is processing large requests where each using heap to full 40 GB and non-heap (memory mapped files) requirement on high side, the processing time increases drastically as page fault increases.
I want to manage this situation by restricting number of large request going to same node and keeping 10 pod / node in all other cases.
Note that node is having total RAM 456 GB.
